# Visual Studio Extensions Get Project Path

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I'm writing an extension for Visual Studio 2017, the extension is available in the context menu of a project (by right-clicking etc) using

```
IDM_VS_CTXT_PROJNODE
```

My question is when I enter

```
private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

how do I get the project path?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check the following code, which use the SVsShellMonitorSelection service you can get a reference to the selected hierarchy as a IVsHierarchy, which in turn allows me to get a reference to the selected object. This may then be cast to classes such as Project, ProjectItem, etc, based on what is selected in the Solution Explorer.

```
private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string message = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Inside {0}.MenuItemCallback()", this.GetType().FullName);
            string title = "ItemContextCommand";

            IntPtr hierarchyPointer, selectionContainerPointer;
            Object selectedObject = null;
            IVsMultiItemSelect multiItemSelect;
            uint projectItemId;

            IVsMonitorSelection monitorSelection =
                    (IVsMonitorSelection)Package.GetGlobalService(
                    typeof(SVsShellMonitorSelection));

            monitorSelection.GetCurrentSelection(out hierarchyPointer,
                                                 out projectItemId,
                                                 out multiItemSelect,
                                                 out selectionContainerPointer);

            IVsHierarchy selectedHierarchy = Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(
                                                 hierarchyPointer,
                                                 typeof(IVsHierarchy)) as IVsHierarchy;

            if (selectedHierarchy != null)
            {
                ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(selectedHierarchy.GetProperty(
                                                  projectItemId,
                                                  (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_ExtObject,
                                                  out selectedObject));
            }

            Project selectedProject = selectedObject as Project;

            string projectPath = selectedProject.FullName;

            // Show a message box to prove we were here
            VsShellUtilities.ShowMessageBox(
                this.ServiceProvider,
                message,
                projectPath,
                OLEMSGICON.OLEMSGICON_INFO,
                OLEMSGBUTTON.OLEMSGBUTTON_OK,
                OLEMSGDEFBUTTON.OLEMSGDEFBUTTON_FIRST);
        }
```

Comment: This does the job nicely. Thank you.